# does vlc supports "normvol" module in android?

Tags: normalization, vlc

Added these configuration changes in VLCOptions.java:

```
options.add("--audio-filter=normvol")
options.add("--norm-buff-size=20")
options.add("--norm-max-level=2")
```

But in the logs could find:

> libvlc audio filter: using audio filter module "scaletempo"

We tried the same approach in vlc command line its selecting the "normvol" module.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
options.add("--audio-filter=volnorm")
```